# prove change of basis matrix is unitary

Tags: linear-algebra

As the title, let $(V,\langle,\rangle)$ be a complex inner product space and assume $S_1=(u_1,\ldots,u_n)$, $S_2=(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ are orthonormal bases of $V$. Prove that the change of basis matrix $M_ IV(S_2,S_1)$ is a unitary matrix.

(There is a hint that let $S$ be the operator s.t. $S(u_i)=v_i$ and prove this is a unitary operator.)

Comment: It's always a good idea to show a bit of your work, then show us where you're stuck and ask a specific question (as opposed to just stating the problem straight out of the book).

Answer (score 12):

We need to show that $\langle Mx,My\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle$ for all $x,y$.  By definition, the change of basis matrix $M$ has the property that

$$
Mu_i=v_i
$$

Let $x=\alpha_1u_1+\ldots+\alpha_nu_n$ and $y=\beta_1u_1+\ldots\beta_nu_n$.  Then, since $\{u_i\}$ is an orthonormal basis, $\langle u_i,u_j\rangle=\delta_{ij}$, the Kronecker delta.  Thus, by expanding out the inner product $\langle x,y\rangle$, we see that 
$$
\langle x,y\rangle=\sum_j\alpha_j\bar{\beta}_j
$$

Now compute $\langle Mx,My\rangle$:

$$
\begin{align*}
\langle Mx,My\rangle&=\langle M(\alpha_1u_1+\ldots+\alpha_nu_n),M(\beta_1u_1+\ldots+\beta_nu_n)\rangle\\
&=\langle \alpha_1Mu_1+\ldots+\alpha_nMu_n,\beta_1Mu_1+\ldots+\beta_nMu_n\rangle\\
&=\langle \alpha_1v_1+\ldots+\alpha_nv_n,\beta_1v_1+\ldots+\beta_nv_n\rangle\\
&=\sum_i\sum_j\alpha_i\bar{\beta}_j\langle v_i,v_j\rangle
\end{align*}
$$

Since $\{v_i\}$ is orthonormal, $\langle v_i,v_j\rangle=\delta_{ij}$, and so the above is exactly $\langle x,y\rangle$

Comment: why is this true?
" By definition, the change of basis matrix M has the property that : Mui=vi"?
is $Mui=av_1+bv_2....cv_n$(a,b.. scalars) ?

Comment: Not quite, u_i is a single vector. M would convert it to one single vector in the other basis. I.e. M * u_i = v_i, for any i, but a single one.